# How to expand bash parameters within a quote within a quote?

Tags: bash

Here's a bash script line I'm trying to do:

```
psql -c 'GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON DATABASE "$PROJECT_ID" to "$PROJECT_ID";'
```

As expected, it doesn't work because bash doesn't interpret anything inside single quotes. Swapping the single and double quotes doesn't work for the same reason.

Solution?

EDIT: What I said about swapping isn't correct -- a bad assumption on my part; however, don't want to swap due to ensure the psql statement still works.

Comment: Swapping will work just fine. Single quotes inside a double quoted string do not inhibit variable expansion.

Comment: Well -- swapping won't work _quite_ fine because single quotes and double quotes have different meanings to SQL.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you're sure that double-quotes are correct in this SQL statement:

```
psql -c 'GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON DATABASE "'"$PROJECT_ID"'" to "'"$PROJECT_ID"'";'
```

Here's why that works: String quoting shell is done on a *character-by-character* basis; we don't need to quote the whole string the same way, and so can concatenate several differently-quoted string subsets together.

In this case, those substrings are:

```
'GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON DATABASE "'
"$PROJECT_ID"
'" to "'
"$PROJECT_ID"
'";'
```

Thus, when we want to pass a literal `"` as part of our string, we enclose it in single-quotes; and when we want to expand a variable, we put it in double quotes.

Comment: Alternately: `psql -c "GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON DATABASE \"$PROJECT_ID\" to \"$PROJECT_ID\";"`